# Does Veganism actually do anything in-game?

Tags: surviving-mars

One of the traits in Surviving Mars is Vegan. The description just says "don't worry, they'll tell you."

All of the food in the game seems to be plant-based so what, if anything, does Veganism do?

Comment: Well, there is one breakthrough tech that give you access to some king of non-plant food, but I don't think that the game makes the difference. I believe that this trait is just for fun.

Comment: @Alien-47 "Some kind of" describes it well. Want to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: I didn't give you any reliable information, so I don't think my comment has the quality of a proper answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the wiki:

> Has decreased Comfort when living near a Ranch and won't work in such
>   buildings.
>   Has increased Comfort when away from Ranches.
>   Farm in the Dome +2 Comfort every Sol.
>   Ranch in the Dome -2 Comfort every Sol.

Source: https://survivingmars.paradoxwikis.com/Colonists

There is also an achievement called *Dream of a Green Mars* that you get if your colony reaches 200 Vegans.

Comment: This answer is correct for the current version of the game. I believe the other answers on this question were written before these effects were in the game.

Answer (score 7):

The Project Laika DLC brought ranches and animals into the mix. Vegans now take a comfort penalty if there is a ranch in their dome.

Answer (score 6):

Gameplay wise: No, they don't.

However: There is an achievment -> **Dream of a Green Mars** -> Have 200 vegans in your colony.